# C++ Inheritance. Changing Object data Types

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with forcing data type changes has on my own objects. I have a base class say `A` and two classes derived from `A` called `B` and `C`. I pass objects `B` and `C` to a function that checks which type of object it is (`B` or `C`). Here is some example code below and the question to my problem:

```
enum ClassType {"B", "C"};

class A {
  protected:
     m_Type;

  public:
     ClassType Type() { return m_Type}
     ...
     ...
};

class B : public A {
   otherMemberFunctions();

}

 class C : public A {
   otherMemberFunctions();

}


void WhatType(vector<A*>* candidates){


  vector<B*> b_candidates(0);
  vector<C*> c_candidates(0);

  for(int i = 0; i < candidates->size(); i++){

    if(candidates->at(i)->Type() == B ){

      B* b = (B*) candidates->at(i);
      b_candidates(b);
   }

  //Same idea for Object C
  }
}
```

I would then use `WhatType(vector<A*>* candidates)` as follows

```
vector<B*>* b_example

WhatType((vector<A*>*) b_exmaple)
```

When I have filled the new `vector` b_candidates in the function `WhatType`. Will I still have access to the member functions in the `B` object or will I only have the access to the member functions in the base class `A`?

I am confused to what happens with the object when I change the type of the object.

Here

```
WhatType((vector<A*>*) b_exmaple)
```

and here

```
B* b = (B*) candidates->at(i);
```

Comment: I'll +1, there's no reason for the code to need to be compilable here.  He made a clearly readable question in my opinion.

Comment: From what I see you are not using C++ polymorphism

Comment: Don't use C-casts, they are horribly unsafe. For example you can't cast a `vector<B*>*` to a `vector<A*>*` and the program would be completely in its right to format your hard disk as soon as you try to do so...

Comment: What do you intend this line: `b_candidates(b);` to do? `std::vector` doesn't have `operator()(T)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive a pointer to a polymorphic object you have two types: the "static" type of the object, which, in your case, will be `A *`, and its "dynamic" or "real" type, that depends on what was actually assigned to it.

Casting your `A *` to `B *` forces the compiler to consider that pointer as a pointer to `B`; this is safe as long as you actually know that that pointer *is actually a pointer to `B`*, otherwise the compiler will start writing nonsensical code (invoking `B` methods on data of another type).

The checks you are trying to implement are a homegrown version of RTTI, which is a mechanism that allows you to know which is the "real type" of a pointer or a reference to a polymorphic class, and to perform that kind of casts safely. Check out `typeid` and `dynamic_cast` on your C++ manual for more info about it. (Incidentally, IIRC `dynamic_cast` is not only for safety in case the dynamic type is wrong, but it may perform also some extra magic on your pointer if you use it in complicated class hierarchies; so, avoid C-style casting for polymorphic classes)

By the way, in general it's considered "code smell" to have to manually check the "real type" of the pointer in order to cast it and use its methods: the OOP ideal would be being able to do the work only though `virtual` methods available in the base class.

---

***Big warning:*** RTTI works *only* on polymorphic classes, i.e. classes that have at least one virtual method. On the other hand, if you are building a class hierarchy where objects are being passed around as pointers to the base class you'll almost surely want to have a `virtual` destructor, so that's no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cast to `B*`, you will have access to `B`'s members.

Comment: Hi Igor. Could you expand on this answer. What is actually happening when I am changing from object B to A and then back to A.

Comment: You are not changing the actual object, you are just casting the pointer. So it doesn't change (or slice) the object. There is still a B there, and you can access its members. (Dynamic_cast and RTTI are safer, like other answers say, but your way will work fine too)

Answer (score 1):

The *actual* type of the objects does not change, of course, but if you only have a pointer (or reference) to the base class you can not access fields specific to the sub-classes.

What you can do to access sub-class fields is to use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to cast it to the sub-class:

```
A *a = new B;  // We cant reach the members of class B in a
B *b = dynamic_cast<B *>(a);  // But now we have a proper pointer to B
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if you had an object of type `B` instantiated on the heap and held by a pointer of type `A`. you can only see type `A`'s member functions, to access type `B`'s member functions you have to  `static_cast<B*>` which is what the ... "(`B*`)" ... is doing.

`dynamic cast` is better as it will return a `null` if the conversion is not possible. but of course it happens a run-time so there's a penalty.

Answer (score -1):

As `B` and `C` are `À` derived, a `vector<B *>` and `vector<C *>` contains `A` base class objects. If you ensure to set your `A::m_Type` attribute in your constructor, you will no have problems:

```
enum ClassType {'B', 'C'};    // see I modified your definition

class A {
    protected:
         ClassType m_Type;

    public:
         ClassType Type() { return m_Type};
    ...
    ...
};

class B : public A {
    public:
         B() : m_Type('B') {}
         ....
};
```

Using this, you will check without problems your `B` and `C`objects. After that, as you are casting base objects to derived ones, you will have fully access to their public methods and attributes.