# Accessing an overridden base class member using a derived class object (C#)

Tags: c#, inheritance

Given 2 Types

```
class A { public virtual void Hello() { Console.WriteLine("A"); } }
class B : A { public override void Hello() { Console.WriteLine("B"); } }
```

and an instance of 'B' 
`B b = new B();`

Can I access the `Hello()` method of `A` thru `b` ? (I can think of exposing A as property in B but not sure if there is another way)

I knew this is possible in [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871864/accessing-overridden-base-class-member-from-derived-class-object) but was scratching my head in c#.

**PS**:Please no conversations around 'why do you want this?' or 'this is a bad design' etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not from the outside.

From the *inside*, the instance can call that, via `base.Hello()`, so you could add a:

```
public void Foo() { base.Hello(); }
```

Comment: Ha.. so I asked a question that even Marc couldn't answer,lol :).
I was aware of 'base',but was wondering about access from outside.

Comment: @AntonyThomas oh, I can answer it: the answer is: "not from the outside". If you try to cheat by static-calling it in IL, the CLI will throw an "operation could destabilize the runtime". It **will not let you** do that.

Comment: So, I thought I can expose the base(`A`) thru a propery in `B` as `public A aProperty { get { return base; } }` but the compiler complains. So isn't there any way I can expose the **base** from the **derived**?

Comment: @AntonyThomas `base` is just a keyword that allows you to access base-class members. The problem is that `b` *is* an object of class `B`, so the entry in the vtable for `Hello()` points to `B.Hello()`. You have no way of getting to `A.Hello()`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks!! What got me confused is the structural similarity between `this` and `base`. Since `return this` works, I thought `return base` should also work. Is there a quick reference link that would teach me more about **vtable** ? I have read _CLR via C#_ but could not recollect much about v-tables

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in c#. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can try shadowing:

```
class A { public virtual void Hello() { Console.WriteLine("A"); } }
class B : A { public new void Hello() { Console.WriteLine("B"); } }
```

Then you can do:

```
        A b = new B();
        b.Hello(); //prints A
       (B)b).Hello(); //prints B

       B b1 = new B();
       b1.Hello(); //prints B
```

Comment: This is interesting. I thought the behavior should be the same for `override` and `new`. Can you give me technical explanation as to why this happens?

Comment: @Antony with the `new`, the second `Hello` (in `B`) is in a *completely separate* v-table record etc; completely unrelated to polymorphism - basically, just a method that happens to have the same name. Usually, this (method hiding) is discouraged.